# How to properly generate xml in Hibernate framework

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I am using MS SQL database server for data and I have Hibernate framework for db mapping. I need to generate specific data (select ... from...) to the xml but have no idea how. I tried searching online but nothing...

I have 2 ideas but you may advice more experienced approach to this problem.

1. Generate xml at db layer with usage of FOR XML within the select.  -> here I dont know what would be the result from select in hibernate...? String? dont know.
2. Retrieve list from DB and then use java to convert this list into xml, for example using this> https://www.javatpoint.com/jaxb-marshalling-example

What do you suggest? Thanks

Comment: You might not need the xml definition, as Hibernate can also be mapped with JPA.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different parameters that could be considered as a basis to decide about the best approach (e.g. Is it important to be database independent? Is there any xml schema provided as a basis to generate the output? How the output is going to be used/accessed?, etc.)

If the output you're going to generate is something like the plain dump of the data and it would be used in future to import data into the database (or similar usages), then maybe just generating the output in database layer would be enough. But most of the time this is not the case. I highly recommend to generate the output in the application layer so that you would have a better control over the way it's going to be produced and customized later. You can fetch data using normal hibernate query and use (as you mentioned) JAX-B to serialize it into XML.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't generate the XML at the database level. Since you're already using Hibernate, you can turn your entity object into a data transfer object (DTO), which is basically the same object, but this time intended to be marshalled and unmarshalled by library. Rather than JAXB, you may want to look at Jackson, which is a bit easer to use (Google for `xml jackson`), and if somebody ever decides that the output should be in JSON or YAML instead, it's very easy to change.